# Is it possible to avoid showing app to user when tapping on a push notification in iOS?

Tags: swift, push-notification

I want the application not be shown when tapping on the notification.
I want to do some background task or just simply open a URL but not the application. 
For instance, I found that I can simply add web view in my application or open the browser to open the url, but how can I prevent showing the application(not bring it to foreground)? 
I also don't want to do the background task with silent push notification as I want to show this notification to the user.

Comment: Check these methods here https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/SchedulingandHandlingLocalNotifications.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH5-SW14.

Comment: When you know that app is launched from the notification then you should be able to handle the first UI, in your case webView or whatever you want.

Comment: @Kamran thanks, but I don't want to show the web view in my app I want to open the url in browser and not show the app to user

Comment: You can simply use UIApplication.shared.openURL when the app is opened from a notification.

Comment: It’s opens automatically. However you can implement the notification actions instead.

Comment: @koropok so the user see that the app is opened?

Comment: @Mannopson yes exactly, I could do this with notification action, the app was not shown to the user but it did some background task. I wonder if it could be done without notification action.

Comment: @FattanehTalebi It’s the system responsibility. I think you can’t implement.